# How to set session cookie http-only in weblogic version 8

Tags: weblogic8.x

Is cookieHttpOnly available in Weblogic 8.x ?? I need to set the session cookies to HTTP only for security reasons and unable to find anything in the weblogic.xml deployment descriptor.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/weblogic_xml.html

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

httpOnly cookie attribute is available from weblogic 9.2 onwards.

But there is a work around to this, check: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTPOnly

For 9.2 see [Weblogic descriptor elements for 9.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/weblogic_xml.html)